# How to stop a moving object exactly where i want

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a code which calculates the difference of 2 game objects and then swaps there position by slowly moving them but i cant find a way to make them stop exactly when they reach the other object position. Any help? I tried a couple ways but i didn't manage to make them stop exactly where i wanted. Note: I want first object to stop exactly at movedSecondTilePos and second object at movedFirstTilePos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P42VB0BSBnI

The code which saves there position while they are on air and then swaps there position.

EDIT:  I updated the code and i am getting very close with this code but still not 100% the same position as i want.

```
    //Saves Moved Positions of Both Tiles
    Vector3 movedFirstTilePos = firstTileObj.transform.position;
    Vector3 movedSecondTilePos = secondTileObj.transform.position;

    // Calculate the Difference of each Tile from the other
    Vector3 firstTilePosDifference = firstTileObj.transform.position - secondTileObj.transform.position;
    Vector3 secondTilePosDifference = secondTileObj.transform.position - firstTileObj.transform.position;


    //Move First Tile to Second Tile Position and vise versa
    while (firstTileObj.transform.position != movedSecondTilePos) {
        firstTileObj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(firstTileObj.transform.position, movedSecondTilePos, tileMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        secondTileObj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(secondTileObj.transform.position, movedFirstTilePos, tileMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    Debug.Log ("Swaped Tiles!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like i found the solution my self :) 
I used this code to move both tiles as close as i can and then used the second code to move them perfectly without making it seem weird.

First Code:

```
firstTileObj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(firstTileObj.transform.position, movedSecondTilePos, tileMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
secondTileObj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(secondTileObj.transform.position, movedFirstTilePos, tileMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Second Code:

```
    //Moves Perfectly Both Tiles
    firstTileObj.transform.position = originalSecondTilePos;
    secondTileObj.transform.position = originalFirstTilePos;
```

Answer (score 1):

A better option will be using unity `Vector3.MoveTowards` with speed calulated according to the distance of object.

```
// Calculate the speed in which the tile should move
float distance= (firstTileObj.transform.position - secondTileObj.transform.position).magnitude;

//In time seconds, the time will reach it's destination
float time = 2;
tileMoveSpeed = distance/time;

firstTileObj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(firstTileObj.transform.position, movedSecondTilePos, tileMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
secondTileObj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(secondTileObj.transform.position, movedFirstTilePos, tileMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: What is the difference of Vector3.MoveTowards and Vector3.Lerp ? Lerp is faster the more far you are and slower the closest you are?

Comment: Lerp moves the value from a to b with respect to a value alpha. For example, a =  10, b = 20, and alpha = 0. Then

Comment: Lerp moves the value from a to b with respect to a value alpha. For example, a =  10, b = 20, and alpha = 0, then the result value will be a(which is 10). If alpha value is 1, then the result value will be b(which is 20). Any value >0 and <1, the result value will be in between a and b. In the case of movetowards, its moves a constant value. So for far objects, lerp will seem faster than MoveTowards unless update the move speed according to the distance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i didn't know exactly how lerp works but i could see that it's faster at start and slower at end especially the very last milliseconds.